# Is it more efficient to join a table without selecting the columns you want, or to join on a subselection of columns from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

The closest I could find to this question was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348537/is-it-better-to-select-before-joining) but it is not quite what I am looking for because their example seems like it would be cutting their selection down significantly (cutting one table down to only those with a specified ID) whereas my example will have millions of rows involved.

Let's say table a and table b both have 50 columns and 1 million+ rows.

Would it be more efficient to do:

```
SELECT 
    a.person, 
    cats, 
    dogs, 
    birds, 
    gerbils
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
ON a.person = b.person
```

Or is it better to do:

```
SELECT 
    a1.person, 
    cats, 
    dogs, 
    birds, 
    gerbils
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        person,
        cats,
        dogs
    FROM
        a
) a1
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        person,
        birds,
        gerbils
    FROM
        b
) b1
ON a.person = b.person
```

My instinct tells me the second is probably worse because it seems like it would be trying to hold more data in memory than the first. I assume that the first query only holds in memory exactly what it is joined, while the second might be holding millions of rows of data, subselected down to the columns specified. Am I right in thinking this?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the responses everyone, it took me a while to test this because my actual query is pretty extensive and I couldn't find one little error. The first one is definitely more efficient. It completed in 30 seconds whereas the first one wouldn't finish after running for hours which makes me think I was overloading the resources.

Comment: Most query optimizers that I know of won't care which way you do it. Is there a specific RDBMS you are concerned about? If so, please tag it.

Comment: First guess, it won't matter, because of what SqlZim said.  Second guess, the first will perform better, and in any case there is no way in hell that the first could perform worse. But, of course, the only way to find out for sure is to benchmark it yourself.  Don't forget to post your findings.

Answer (score 1):

The only time the "select list" makes a difference in performance is when the query can be completely resolved in an index and no table access is required; so, in general, select only the columns you need to use and stay away from the LOBS if you don't need them.

Comment: True, but this doesn't answer the actual question asked. The OP wants to know if there is a performance difference when querying a subquery vs. querying the table directly.

Comment: I think you are splitting hairs.  The OP intent boiled down to is there a performance delta by changing the select list.